# List does not appear in the app interface

Tags: flutter, dart

The idea is that a list appears on my app screen and is updated as I add texts to the textField, but in my tests the list appears empty even though I put test items there.

image error

[image: error output]

flutter version 1.0.0

dependences

path_provider: ^1.1.0

code atualization

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List _listaTarefas = [];

  Future<File> _pegarArquivo() async {
    final diretorio = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return File("${diretorio.path}/dados.json");
  }

  _salvarArquivo() async {
    var arquivo = await _pegarArquivo();

    Map<String, dynamic> tarefa = Map();
    tarefa['titulo'] = "Teste";
    tarefa['realizada'] = false;
    _listaTarefas.add(tarefa);

    String dados = json.encode(_listaTarefas);
    arquivo.writeAsString(dados);
  }


  _lerArquivo() async {
    try {
      final arquivo = await _pegarArquivo();
      return arquivo.readAsString();
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _lerArquivo().then((dados) {
      setState(() {
        _listaTarefas = json.decode(dados);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _salvarArquivo();

    print('Resultado' + _listaTarefas.toString());

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Lista de tarefas'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Adicionar Tarefa'),
                    content: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Digite sua tarefa',
                      ),
                      onChanged: (text) {},
                    ),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                        child: Text('cancelar'),
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Text('Salvar'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                });
          }),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _listaTarefas.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(_listaTarefas[index]['titulo']),
                    );
                  }))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The problem

When you declare the following method

```
_lerArquivo() async {
  try {
    final arquivo = await _pegarArquivo();
    return arquivo.readAsStringSync();
  } catch (e) {
    return Text('erro');
  }
}
```

you're returning a String when you do

```dart
return arquivo.readAsStringSync();
```

and a Text when you do

```dart
return Text('erro');
```

#### The solution

To fix this, you can either

1. return a string in the second `return`:

```
_lerArquivo() async {
  try {
    final arquivo = await _pegarArquivo();
    return arquivo.readAsStringSync();
  } catch (e) {
    return 'erro';
  }
}
```

2. do nothing:

```
_lerArquivo() async {
  final arquivo = await _pegarArquivo();
  return arquivo.readAsStringSync();
}
```

#### The good practice

To avoid future errors (i.e. transform run-time errors into compile-time errors), declare your variable types, return types and type parameters explicitely:

```
String _lerArquivo() async {
  try {
    final arquivo = await _pegarArquivo();
    return arquivo.readAsStringSync();
  } catch (e) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply friend but it still didn't work, the app is starting normal but the items in the list don't appear on the screen, it appears as an empty list []. I updated the code and got a new error message

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace (i.e. the lines starting with "E/flutter" below "Tried calling: length" in your error image)? It'd also help if you post it as text.